# SQLLDR escape special character such as <96>

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Experts,

I have issue loading data with having special characters like the row below using SQLLDR.

```
VOSSN-SMUP|VOSSN MANUAL STATUS UPDATE FEE|VOSSN|Note Update|SM Completed <96> Final||
```

My control file.

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
INTO TABLE PROD_MAP_T
SINGLEROW
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
REQUEST_TYPE        CHAR,
STATUS              CHAR,
SUB_TYPE            CHAR,
SUB_TYPE            CHAR,
REVERIFICATION      CHAR,
ISRUSH              CHAR,
CLIENT_ID           CHAR
)
```

Data after loading Looks like:

```
SM Completed � Batch Sent to IRS
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the command? There are 7 fields and you provided only 5

Comment: @JorgeCampos the question is about the field#5 , so I thought rest isn't required.

Comment: It is always good to provide everything so we can test your case in our environments.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Agree. In that case, I have removed first two rows as they are external. I have put in the workable file.Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: What do you want to happen, or see in the table? What data type is the column, what is your database character set, and how are you displaying it? Specifically, which client, and which client character set? And what is your NLS_LANG when you run SQL\*Loader?

Comment: @AlexPoole I want the data to be loaded as it is . When I select the column it should contain <96>. The column is VARCHAR2. NLS_LANG = AMERICAN.

Comment: So what is the issue - that it isn't displaying as you expect when you query it? What do you expect/want to actually see? (And it's the bit after AMERICAN that tells you the character set)

Comment: @AlexPoole when the target system ( C program) does the select , it is getting this as `SM Completed � Batch Sent to IRS`

Comment: Please post the result of "SELECT DUMP(the_col) FROM the_tab" for the row/column of interest. That will tell you what actually got stored in the table by the load.